# Devise and simple-private-messages implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, messaging, messagebox, inbox

I want to build a user inbox system and choosing this simple-private-messages gem as the backbone.  However, the documentation of this gem is rather primitive.
I've generated the scaffold of this gem, however, I don't know what key the gem is used to define the recipient/sender.

I want the current_user is able to message a particular user via the link of its profile page and then it will automatically fill the username into the "to" field.

Would anyone please construct a demo app illustrating the implementation of this gem, thanks a lot.

Please advise.

Comment: I believe it does not work like this. It is you who create demo app, and if you have difficulties with one particular issue, you ask for help

Comment: OK, I'm generating such an app. Don't consider me an indolent coder.

Comment: I have used the "mailboxer" gem and a custom user model (but you simply need to say to the model to act_as_messagable" so it doesn`t really matter what model you have). The documentation is quite good and understandable. As of the feature you want (to send a message to a particular user) you can simply pass the variable to the view. Here is a link to the [gem](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer)

Comment: mailboxer seems too complicated and beef up resources.  Would there be any lightweight gem? I've considered acts_as_messageable and yet the problem is how to implement it in the view layer. I chose simple private messages because it provides a view scaffold, however, its coding style still in the rails 2 age, errors like "error_message_on" always prompt out. Should I switch to "acts-as-messageable" instead?

Comment: Can you explain particularly why do you avoid mailboxer? I am just wondering if I have to consider switching it to something else too ;) It seems that acts-as-messageable is pretty similar to mailboxer (functionality at least) and the views should not be hard to implement.